# Spring Data MongoDB: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We are doing some upgrades in our app, and are currently trying to use `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE`, an upgrade from `1.5.10.RELEASE`. Currently, we are having difficulty in finding ways to suppress Spring Data error related to database name constraint. For so long, we've been using MongoDB, with databases named with special character '#'. Other than continuing using `1.5.10.RELEASE` and renaming the databases (which is not possible for the moment since the databases are also used by other apps), what possible solutions/tricks/hacks could be done to repress the error?

**Updated**

Shortened Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:82) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration.mongoDbFactory(MongoDataAutoConfiguration.java:92) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$426b7ff2.CGLIB$mongoDbFactory$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$426b7ff2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8ebb83e3.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$426b7ff2.mongoDbFactory(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Hi @mp911de, Just updated with stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, please create an own `MongoDbFactory` as Spring Data MongoDB's [`SimpleMongoDbFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoDbFactory.html) enforces a name matching rule.

I filed [DATAMONGO-1903](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1903) to address the issue.